# Haskell Input Return Tuple

Tags: haskell, io, interactive

i wonder can a IO() function return tuple because i would like to get these out of this function as input for another function.

```
investinput :: IO()->([Char], Int)
investinput = do
 putStrLn "Enter Username : "
 username <- getLine

 putStrLn "Enter Invest Amount : "
 tempamount <- getLine
 let amount = show  tempamount
 return (username, amount)
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Try removing the type signature, changing `show` to `read`, and adding `:: Int` at the end of the line where you added `read`. Then load it in GHCi, try it out, and ask for the type with `:t`. It won't be what you have here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IO in Haskell doesn't work like IO in the languages you're used to.  All functions in Haskell must be pure: that is, if a function `f` is called with the argument `x`, there must be no difference between calling it once, twice, or a hundred times.  Consider what this means for IO, though.  Naïvely, `getLine` should have the type `getLine :: String`, or perhaps `getLine :: () -> String`.  (`()` is the unit type, whose only value is `()`; it's sort of like a void type in a C-like language, but there is a single value of it.)  But this would mean that every time you wrote `getLine`, it would have to return the *same string*, which is not what you want.  This is the purpose of the `IO` type: to encapsulate *actions*.  These actions are distinct from functions; they represent *impure* computation (though they themselves are pure).  A value of type `IO a` represents an action which, when executed, returns a value of type `a`.  Thus, `getLine` has type `getLine :: IO String`: every time the action is evaluated, a `String` is produced (by reading from the user).  Similarly, `putStr` has type `putStr :: String -> IO ()`; it is a function which takes a string and returns an action which, when run, returns no useful information… but, as a side effect, prints something to the screen.

You are attempting to write a function of type `IO () -> ([Char], Int)`.  This would be a function which took as input an action and returned a tuple, which is *not* what you want.  You want an `IO (String, Int)`—an action which, when run, produces a tuple consisting of a string (which is a synonym for `[Char]`) and an integer.  You're almost there with your current code, too!  This is what you'll need instead:

```
investinput :: IO (String, Int)
investinput = do
  putStrLn "Enter Username : "
  username <- getLine
  putStrLn "Enter Invest Amount : "
  tempamount <- getLine
  let amount = read tempamount
  return (username, amount)
```

Notice that I've only made two changes (and removed a blank line).  First, I've changed the type of the function, like I said above.  Second, I changed `show` into `read`.  The `show` function has the type `Show a => a -> String`: it is a function which takes anything which can be shown and produces a string representing it.  *You* wanted `read`, which has the type `Read a => String -> a`: given a string, it parses it and returns some readable value.

The other thing you asked about is returning a tuple `(String, Int)` instead of an action `IO (String, Int)`.  There is no pure way to do this; in other words, there is no pure function `IO a -> a`.  Why is this?  Because `IO a` represents an impure action which depends on the real world.  If we had such a function `impossibleRunIO :: IO a -> a`, then we would want it to be the case that `impossibleRunIO getLine == impossibleRunIO getLine`, since the function must be pure.  But this is useless, as we would want `impossibleRunIO` to be able to actually interact with the real world!  Thus, this pure function is impossible.  Everything that enters `IO` can never leave.  This is what `return` does: it is a function with, in this case<sup>1</sup>, the type `return :: a -> IO a`, which enables you to place pure values into `IO`.  For any `x`, `return x` is an action which, when run, always produces `x`.  This is why you have to end your `do` block with the `return`: `username` is a pure value you extracted from an action, and as such is only visible within the `do` block.  You need to lift it into `IO` before the outside world can see it.  The same is true of `amount`/`tempamount`.

And just for completeness's sake: there is some overarching theory behind this which ties it together.  But it's not necessary at all for beginning Haskell programming.  What I would recommend doing is structuring most of your code as pure functions which fold, spindle, and mutilate your data.  Then construct a thin (as thin as possible) `IO` front layer which interacts with said functions.  You'll be surprised how little IO you need!

1: It actually has a more general type, but that's not relevant for the moment.

Comment: Actually what i want is something like this
test = savefile investinput 
The invest input IO string is passes to savefile in order to save
investinput :: IO ([Char], Int)
main = do
    (username, amount) <- investinput
If i do like this the main still have IO() type which is not i want. The test function should have different type.

Comment: I can't quite follow what you wrote, but I'll try to respond to it.  You said that you don't want `main` to have the type `IO ()`.  Let's think about what `main` is.  It represents your whole program, so it must be some sort of impure action; and since it's your whole program, it can't return anything useful.  Thus, it *must* have the type `IO ()`.  And asking for it to have another type is like asking your C compiler to accept `double main(char* x, void (*y)())`—it's forbidden.  If this isn't enough information yet, why don't you edit your question to explain what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: Your point is of course correct, but as a bit of trivia, `main` is only required to have "type `IO t` for some type `t`" according to the report. So `main = getLine` is a valid (and useless) program. This is completely irrelevant to peterwkc's question, but it's a funny little fact that surprised me when I came across it.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, you're almost there but I think you want the signature:

```
investinput :: IO ([Char], Int)
```

... then from the calling function you can do something like:

```
main = do
    (username, amount) <- investinput
    ....
```

I think you want to read tempamount rather than show though.

Comment: Thanks it works but why this type signature is not working.

investinput :: IO() -> ([Char], Int)

Comment: I need to return tuple rather than return IO tuple. 

nvestinput :: IO([Char], Int)
investinput = do
 putStrLn "Enter Username : "
 username <- getLine
 
 putStrLn "Enter Invest Amount : "
 tempamount <- getLine
 let amount = read tempamount :: Int
 putStrLn ""
 return (username, amount)

Comment: I started trying to describe what's happening here using the IO box analogy, but I don't think a quick description is really helpful. There is no substitute for reading up on monads to understand why IO ([Char], Int) is the type. http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/ is a great resource for this

Answer (score 2):

An IO function that produces a tuple would have type `IO (a, b)`, in this case:

```
investinput :: IO ([Char], Int)
```

A signature of `IO () -> ([Char], Int)` would mean that the function takes a parameter of type `IO ()` and produces a tuple from that, which is not what you want.

Generally there are no restrictions on the types an IO function (or a function in a different monad) can return, you can chose the types however you like.

Comment: A signature of IO () -> ([Char], Int) would mean that the function takes a parameter of type IO () and produces a tuple from that, which is not what you want.

I need a IO input and return tuple. 

Thanks. 

This is what i want.

Comment: No, `IO () -> ...` would mean that you give some IO function *as a parameter* to `investinput`, like calling it with `investinput (print 1)`. That your function uses another function like `getLine` which reads from the console is not reflected in the type signature. The type signature just states what types of parameters a function call expects and what type of return value it will produce.

Comment: The reason i need the IO() -> ([Char, Int]) is because i have another function which expect a tuple to do the computation. 

I also saw some example like this lifM index (readFile "input.txt")
liftM has this signature:
liftM :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
It takes a non-monadic function and transforms it into a monadic function.
fmap index $ readFile "input.txt"
readFile "input.txt" >>= return . index

Please help.

Comment: @peterwkc: If the there is another function that needs a tuple, then this function should take a tuple as a parameter? How does that influence the parameters this function takes? Looking at the definition of the function in the question it doesn't take any parameters, so also its signature can't contain any parameters.

Comment: The investinput should return tuple to another function after perform IO in investinput. 

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question about returning `(String, Int)` rather than `IO (String, Int)` is simple: you can't. Once you're in `IO` you're stuck there. That's part of what it means when people say that Haskell is a "pure" language.

What you want to do is similar to what you're already doing here with `getLine`. The type of `getLine` is `IO String`. When you write `username <- getLine`, you're in effect taking the `String` out of the `IO String`, but this is only possible because you're inside the `do` expression.

You can do exactly the same kind of thing with `investinput` as with `getLine`. Here's an example of how you could use `investinput` in your `main` function:

```
main = do
  (name, amount) <- investinput
  putStrLn $ name ++ " invested $" ++ show amount ++ "."
```

Since you mention `liftM` in a comment, here's a full working version that does the same thing using `liftM` and the reverse bind operator (`=<<`) instead of `do` notation:

```
import Control.Monad (liftM)

investinput :: IO (String, Int)
investinput = do
   putStrLn "Enter Username : "
   username <- getLine
   putStrLn "Enter Invest Amount : "
   amount <- liftM read getLine -- We can also use liftM to get rid of tempamount.
   return (username, amount)

summary :: (String, Int) -> String
summary (name, amount) = name ++ " invested $" ++ show amount ++ "."

main = putStrLn =<< liftM summary investinput
```

This shows how you could use `investinput` with "another function which expects a tuple".

Comment: I try the code but it is not compile. 

import Monad

-- Receive IO input do something
summary :: ([Char], [Char]) -> String
summary (name, amount) = putname ++ 
 " invested $" ++ amount ++ "."

investinput :: IO ()
investinput = do
 putStrLn "Enter Username : "
 username <- getLine
 
 putStrLn "Enter Invest Amount : "
 tempamount <- getLine
 putStrLn "" 

main = putStrLn =<< liftM summary investinput

Comment: Thanks. 

Can you explain these lines of code ? 

liftM summary investinput

What is liftM ? 

It say promote a function into monad. What this mean ?

Comment: I want output of maxinvestinput as input for maximuminvest. Thanks. 
     maxinvest = liftM maximuminvest maxinvestinput
maxinvestinput :: IO()
maxinvestinput = do
str <- readFile "C:\\Invest.txt"
let cont = words str
let mytuple = converttuple cont
let myint = getint mytuple
putStrLn ""
converttuple :: [String] -> [(String, Integer)]
converttuple (x:y:z) = (x, read y):converttuple z
getint :: [(String, Integer)] -> [Integer]
getint (x:xs) = snd (x) : getint xs
maximuminvest :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a
maximuminvest (x:xs)
| x > maxTail = x
| otherwise = maxTail
where maxTail = maximuminvest xs